# ASP.NET How to get HttpException ErrorCode

Tags: asp.net, httpexception

I'm trying to catch and handle a specific HttpException, namely "The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD."

My intention is to add a Catch for the HttpException to the relevant Try block and test for the error code that is generated. Sample code:

```
Try
    // Do some stuff
Catch exHttp As HttpException
    If exHttp.ErrorCode.ToString() = "0x800704CD" Then DoSomething()
Catch ex As Exception
    // Generic error handling
End Try
```

But I can't work out how to extract the error code displayed in the exception (i.e. "0x800704CD") from the HttpException object. Converting the integer value of the ErrorCode property to hex returns "800704CD" so clearly I'm not understanding how this code is generated.

Thanks.

Comment: in the sample code you are assigning 0x800704CD whicgh should generate another exception

Comment: have you tried to print the stack trace and see what does it have

Comment: exHttp.ErrorCode.ToString() returns the integer value of the error code, converted to string e.g. "-2147023667"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try the Below Code:**

```
 Try
    // Do some stuff
        Catch exHttp As HttpException
            If exHttp.ErrorCode = &H800704CD Then DoSomething()
        Catch ex As Exception
    // Generic error handling
        End Try
```

Comment: Thanks RG ATHISH, adding the &H works. Could you explain why though?

Comment: 0x800704CD  for  C#.net , &H800704CD for vb.net

Answer (score 0):

ErrorCode property is an integer so just test for integer value, no reason to convert to hexadecimal or string.

0x in most programming languages means the following characters denote a hexadecimal number, i.e. 0x800704CD means 800704CD will be interpreted as a hexadecimal number. For VB use &H.

More on VB.Net literals:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzy06xhf.aspx